# Vue: Odd issue with extra update cycles with slots

Tags: vuejs3

I was attempting to create a small project to demonstrate why prop stability is important as discussed [here in the Vue docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/best-practices/performance.html#props-stability), but I started seeing odd behavior. Specifically, I get prop stability as expected as long as the child component doesn't have anything passed into it's default slot. However, if anything is passed into the slot all items in the list go through an update cycle (i.e. the onUpdated hook fires), instead of just the affected items.

In other words, given the following code:

```
<li
  v-for="(fruit, index) in fruits"
  :key="index"
  @click="activeId = fruit.id"
>
  <FruitItem :fruit="fruit" :selected="fruit.id === activeId">Remove Me</FruitItem>
</li>
```

A few items of explanation. First, notice that `<FruitItem>` has a `:selected` prop that is set to `fruit.id === activeId`. Also notice that clicking on the parent `<li>` element changes the `activeId` to that item's id. This should create decent prop stability because the expression I'm passing in is a boolean value to the `selected` prop, which for most items in the list will remain false -- only the clicked on item and the previously selected item actually have their `selected` prop value change.

If you remove the text `Remove Me`, then only the effected items go through an update cycle when you click on one of the items. If you put the `Remove Me` text back, then you will see all items in the list go through an update cycle when an item is clicked.

To see the behavior, open the stackblitz and open the browser console. Then click on one of the fruit items. You'll notice that "updated" gets logged 4 times, meaning all 4 instances of the `<FruitItem>` component were updated, even though only the affected items (the newly selected, and newly deselected item) should have been updated.

To see the issue, open up [this Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/update-cycle-slots?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FFruitItem.vue,src%2FApp.vue) and then open up the browser's console. If you click on one of the items you'll see "updated" logged 4 times. This is being logged from the `<FruitItem>`'s `onUpdated` hook. It shouldn't log 4 times, it should log, at most 2 times. Now remove the text `Remove Me` from the `<FruitItem>` so that nothing is being passed into it's default slot. Now click the items again and you'll see that `updated` is only logged twice, which is the expected behavior.

This feels like a bug. Am I missing something?